# How do I detect if a class / variable was imported in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

This is the contents of `script_one.py`:

```
x = "Hello World"
```

This is the contents of `script_two.py`:

```
from script_one import x
print(x)
```

Now, if I ran `script_two.py` the output would be:

```
>>> Hello World
```

What I need is a way to detect if `x` was imported.
This is what I imagine the source code of `script_one.py` would look like:

```
x = "Hello World"
if x.has_been_imported:
  print("You've just imported \"x\"!")
```

Then if I ran `script_two.py` the output *"should"* be:

```
>>> Hello World
>>> You've just imported "x"!
```

What is this called, does this feature exist in Python 3 and how do you use it?

Comment: What if you had written `import script_one` instead?

Comment: So what problem are you trying to solve? Python imports **whole modules**, and then binds additional names to the same objects in the module. You'd have to track reference counts, and that's not reliable at all.

Comment: You'd have to determine the import success within the module that does the importing, not detect if a module was called by an import statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Effort expended on trying to detect this are a waste of time, I'm afraid.

Python imports consist of the following steps:

- Check if the module is already loaded by looking at `sys.modules`.

  - If the module hasn't been loaded yet, load it. This creates a new module object that is added to `sys.modules`, containing all objects resulting from executing the top-level code.
- Bind names in the importing namespace. How names are bound depends on the exact `import` variant chosen.

  - `import module` binds the name `module` to the `sys.modules[module]` object
  - `import module as othername` binds the name `othername` to the `sys.modules[module]` object
  - `from module import attribute` binds the name `attribute` to the `sys.modules[module].attribute` object
  - `from module import attribute as othername` binds the name `othername` to the `sys.modules[module].attribute` object

In this context it is important to realise that Python names are just references; all Python objects (including modules) live on a heap and stand or fall with the number of references to them. See this [great article by Ned Batchelder on Python names](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) if you need a primer on how this works.

Your question then can be interpreted in two ways:

- You want to know the module has been imported. The moment code in the module is executed (like `x = "Hello World"`), it has been imported. All of it. Python doesn't load *just* `x` here, it's all or nothing.
- You want to know if other code is using a specific name. You'd have to track what other references exist to the object. This is a mammoth task involving recursively checking the [`gc.get_referrers()` object chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.get_referrers) to see what other Python objects might now refer to `x`.

The latter goal is made the harder all the further in any of the following scenarios:

- `import script_one`, then use `script_one.x`; references like these could be too short-lived for you to detect.
- `from script_one import x`, then `del x`. Unless something else still references the same string object within the imported namespace, that reference is now gone and can't be detected anymore.
- `import sys; sys.modules['script_one'].x` is a legitimate way of referencing the same string object, but does this count as an import?
- `import script_one`, then `list(vars(script_one).values())` would create a list of all objects defined in the module, but these references are indices in a list, not named. Does this count as an import?

Comment: Hi Martjin, I know it's kind of an old question but that's quite close to the problem I'm trying to solve (my problems are all related to generating stubs files btw). Isn't it possible to learn about whether something was imported or not by looking at its `__module__` property and comparing it against current module?

Comment: @Artur not everything has a `__module__` attribute (strings don’t, for example), and the attribute is writable. Why do you think you need this information?

Comment: Thanks for answering years after the question was asked. I am creating custom stub files and need to iterate over all objects within a module in question. Depending on whether the object (let it be a class definition, a variable or whatever else) was declared within the module or not, I need to treat it a bit differently.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is impossible previously. But ever since python 3.7+ introduces `__getattr__` on module level, looks like it is possible now. At least we can distinguish whether a variable is imported by `from module import varable` or `import module; module.variable`.

The idea is to detect the AST node in the previous frame, whether it is an `Attribute`:

`script_one.py`

```py
def _variables():
  # we have to define the variables 
  # so that it dosen't bypass __getattr__
  return {'x': 'Hello world!'}

def __getattr__(name):
  try:
    out = _variables()[name]
  except KeyError as kerr:
    raise ImportError(kerr)
  
  import ast, sys  
  from executing import Source
  
  frame = sys._getframe(1)
  node = Source.executing(frame).node
  if node is None:
    print('`x` is imported')
  else:
    print('`x` is accessed via `script_one.x`')

  return out
```

`script_two.py`

```py
from script_one import x
print(x)
# `x` is imported
# 'Hello world!'

import script_one
print(script_one.x)
# `x` is accessed via `script_one.x`
# 'Hello world!'
```